# AWS X-Ray not initializing a new segment

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-xray, open-telemetry

I'm using OpenTelemetry with AWS X-Ray to trace E2E messaging between:

Producer (JVM) -> Kafka Broker -> Consumers (Multiple, Python-based)

Generated traces are then send to AWS OTEL Collector which forwards them to AWS X-Ray.

However when I see them from X-Ray consumer trace is displayed as a sub-segment of producer:

[image]

I'm expecting to see consumer as a separate segment.

I've also tried to use AWS X-Ray SDK in the consumer side to explicitly initialize a new segment as following:

```
val traceId = TraceIdData(String(record.headers().headers("X-Amzn-Trace-Id").first().value()))
logger.debug("Trace Id {}, Parent Id {}", traceId.root, traceId.parent)
AWSXRay.beginSegment("Simple Kafka Consumer", traceId.root, traceId.parent)
... some processing ...
AWSXRay.endSegment()
```

However this is still shown as a sub-segment in AWS X-Ray even though I'm beginning a new segment and specifying: `trace_id` and `parent_id`. I have confirmed that both attributes are not null and valid.

How can I generate a new **segment** in AWS X-Ray for this ongoing trace? Preferably, I'd like to do this using OpenTelemetry (agent/sdk/collector), but using AWS X-Ray SDK is also a possibility.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a chat with AWS X-Ray team and they helped me solve my issue.

The reason for this issue is that `awsxray exporter` only creates new segments for Spans when `kind=SpanKind.SERVER`.

I have implemented this (in Python) using OpenTelemetry SDK and explicitely declaring `kind=SpanKind.SERVER` when creating a new span

```
processing_span = self.tracer.start_span(self.service_name, context=current_context, kind=SpanKind.SERVER)
```

Which gives me my desired result of seeing multiple consumers in the Service Map
[image: Service Map]

Unfortunately [OpenTelemetry java instrumentation for Kafka on consumer side](https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-java-instrumentation/blob/main/instrumentation/kafka-clients-0.11/javaagent/src/main/java/io/opentelemetry/javaagent/instrumentation/kafkaclients/KafkaConsumerTracer.java) is automatically creating a new span where kind=CONSUMER which cannot be modified (as part of automatic instrumentation) so the only way to get my desired result is through manual instrumentation.